Errors while working with QMediaPlayer in PySide6
I've noticed a very strange behaviour during my attempt to show video using PySide6 controls. The problem is that when I play the video and start dragging the window, it starts to freeze, skip frames etc. And the following type of messages are in the console:
[AVHWFramesContext @ 00000234DC0DB380] Static surface pool size exceeded.
[h264 @ 00000234CA2C7D40] get_buffer() failed
[h264 @ 00000234CA2C7D40] thread_get_buffer() failed
[h264 @ 00000234CA2C7D40] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 00000234CA2C7D40] no frame!

Moreover, when I press 'exit' button (top right 'cross' sign on Windows), but do not release the button, the same problem occurs. Can you, please, provide some thoughts and information about how to overcome this issue. It is a major problem in my app, so I need somehow to solve it.
I currently use PySide6 6.7.1. I run this app on Windows 10 Pro (22H2 19045.4780). I tested this code on another machine (also Win 10), the same problem occurs.
Below is the minimal example, that reproduces the problem. Just set the field self.video_file_path to some video file on your computer.
from PySide6.QtCore import QUrl
from PySide6.QtMultimedia import QMediaPlayer
from PySide6.QtMultimediaWidgets import QVideoWidget
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
import sys

class VideoPlayer(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(VideoPlayer, self).__init__(parent)

        self.video_file_path = "PATH_TO_YOUT_VIDEO.mp4"

        self.media_player = QMediaPlayer(self)
        self.video_widget = QVideoWidget()
        self.media_player.setVideoOutput(self.video_widget)
        self.media_player.setSource(QUrl.fromLocalFile(self.video_file_path))

        self.play_button = QPushButton()
        self.play_button.setText("Play/Pause")
        self.play_button.clicked.connect(self.play_or_pause)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.video_widget)
        layout.addWidget(self.play_button)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def play_or_pause(self):
        if self.media_player.playbackState() == QMediaPlayer.PlaybackState.PlayingState:
            self.media_player.pause()
        else:
            self.media_player.play()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    player = VideoPlayer()
    player.resize(400, 400)
    player.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())

What I expect is to resolve the described problem, because it has a strong impact on user experience for my app.

The code is pretty standard, meaning that the issue is probably elsewhere and we need more details: OS and Qt versions, and possible configuration aspects that may be related (dm/wm conf if you're on Linux, graphic card, etc.). It's also important to know if you tested on other computers or configurations, and the related results.

@musicamante I've added additional information to my question. I currently use PySide6 6.7.1. I run this app on Windows 10 Pro (22H2 19045.4780). I tested this code on another machine (also Win 10), the same problem occurs.

Does the other machine have a different hardware/software configuration (specifically, the graphics)? Because those errors seem to deal with hardware acceleration, and it would help knowing more about that in your system(s). In any case, you could try to switch to the native windows backend (see the docs), which could temporarily solve the problem. It may be problem in the ffmpeg build that Qt includes, and you should at least consider trying different PySide versions (6.7.2, 6.7.0, or 6.6.3).

@musicamante Yes, I've tested on different machines with different hardware and software setup, the result is the same. Different versions of PySide also do not help. Can you, please, tell, if the provided code works on your setup (if you can test it and have a windows machine)?

I don't have windows machines with that Qt version, on Linux it works without problems. Did you try with files using different video formats (codec, color depth if using HDR, resolutions, etc.)? What PySide versions did you test? Did you test with the windows backend as written above?

I've tried all PySide versions that you recommended (6.7.2, 6.7.0 and 6.6.3). Also, I followed the instuctions on provided article, none of them helped. The same problem for all video files and formats I've tested (mp4, mkv, 4K resolution, 2K resolution, 8-bit color depth).

That's odd, as I've never seen such a report for those errors and/or behavior (and the only similar trace I found for that error doesn't seem to be relevant). Note that the backend link above suggests using export, which is a *nix command, but on Windows it's probably set or setx (I don't really know for sure). Also, mp4 and mkv are containers, they do not define the actual codecs for the streams; did you test with another player (eg. VLC)? I suppose you're running the program natively, not through some kind of virtualization (including WSL), right? Can you try older PySide versions?

Yes, I am running program natively, no virtualization. As for article you mentioned, I used set which is fine for Windows I guess. No problems with VLC were found -- no freezes or missing frames. I've tried around 10 different versions of PySide6 starting from 6.0.0 and none of them resolved the problem.

I know "me too" comments aren't encouraged, but I found this post when searching the same problem myself.
I'm getting the same errors using a slightly different set-up, PyQt6 instead of PySide6.
The video file playback is jittery at the same time, which I assume is connected.
The video files are generally 1080p h264 files in MOV wrappers, so nothing exotic, and unfortunately there are use case limitations where I'll need to make it work without re-encoding the video if it's possible.
